# Best practice for handling data that must persist outside an activity lifecycle in Android?

Tags: android, architecture

When I look at documentation around Android app architecture best practices, all the recommended architectures (MVVM, MVP, etc) seem to tie the datamodels to the view lifecycle. The view holds a reference to the viewmodel/presenter which holds a reference to the model, so when the view is gone, the data is gone. But I have data that I need to persist as long as my app is open.

I'm aware of SharePreferences but my data seems too structured for that. I don't want to have to write and reread the data from a file like with internal storage or sqlite, as the whole point of me keeping this data is to avoid calls like that. The only other option I can think of is to store the data in a singleton, but that seems sub-optimal because then I'll have to keep track of whether the singleton has been initialized.

Are there Android best practices for how to manage persistent data like this?

Comment: Depending on what you're asking, there could be dozens of answers for this.  Singletons, caches, dependency injection, etc.  You may use more than one for an app for different types of data. The question being asked here is too broad.

Comment: How could I narrow it down? I don't understand how dependency injection could be used for this. Where would the data be injected to and from where? When I looked up caches, they seemed more like a way of managing where data is getting pulled from, not storing the data. And I didn't understand how they could be made independent from the activity lifecycle without making them essentially a singleton.

Comment: Essentially static data.  There's a difference between static data and a singleton.  Yes, at some point there will either be a static somewhere (or a variable in an application lifetimed class like Application).  That doesn't mean its a Singleon-  a Singleton is a class where the constructor prevents there from ever being more than one of them at a time.  But the mechanisms on top of the static data matter, and there's a variety of them with different use cases and different negatives.

Comment: AN example-  my company's app has a single Javascript instance shared among all screens.  That is dependency injected into each activity that needs to send it commands.  It also has model objects, those are stored in a WeakReference cache to provide access to them if they already exist (they have a uuid unique key) in memory so instances don't go out of sync, and we go to a database if it isn't in memory yet.  Then we have a few application level variables like the dependency injection contexts held in Application.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best approach for saving state of an application when a configuration changed is to keep the data model in the memory.

So you allow the re-creation of activity, but the presenter/viewmodel must be persisted.

In the case of the AAC, this has already been implemented (ViewModelStore), it is also implemented in some MVP frameworks (Moxy for example), or you can implement it manually with local-singleton in your DI.

Perhaps my answer is exactly what the @Gabe Sechan wanted to say.

Comment: It seems like ViewModelStore still destroys the view model when the activity is destroyed https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-architecture-components-c33b15d89c23. It just allows it to survive configuration changes.